# Was Cary Elwes's evil scientist "Dr. Jonas Miller" a last minute addition to Twister (1996)?

Tags: screenplay, twister

I watched Twister for the first time today and was struck by how much of an afterthought the "evil competing scientist" subplot seemed. So much so that I suspect it may have not been in the original script at all, and perhaps was added at the last minute at the behest of the movie studio.

Beyond the discussions of the troubled writing and filming process for "Twister", as described on the film's Wikipedia page, I know nothing behind the scenes. Is there any evidence about the origin of this character?

Comment: I don't have a copy but the *original* screenplay by Michael Chrichton is described as *"the competition between two rival groups of scientists determined to be the first to put a tracking device inside the funnel of a tornado"* so it seems unlikely

Comment: I didn't have that impression at all .... the race against Dr Miller, the well funded but less talented scientist seems quite integral to the plot to me.  Yes, the character is a stereotype and not very well fleshed out, but I would be astonished if it was a last minute add-on character.  It adds a much needed human element to the drama.